# Shell script: find git folder and execute git command?

Tags: git, shell, unix

I have several git repo in folder and subfolder and i want to cleanup using git reset --hard, can someone guide me ?

```
find /home/me/src -type d -name ".git" -print
```

and execute find ".git" repo

```
git --git-dir=/home/me/src/find1/.git reset --hard
git --git-dir=/home/me/src/find2/.git reset --hard
git --git-dir=/home/me/src/subfolder/find3/.git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard` only works with a working directory. I'm afraid your commands won't do what you expect. You'd have to `cd` into the working directory of the git repository (assuming the `.git` directory is contained within your working directory)

```
find /home/me/src -type d -name '.git' -print0 \
| xargs -0 sh -c 'cd "${1%/.git}"; git reset --hard;' -
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below script. Hope it helps

```
find /home/me/src -name ".git" -type d -exec "git reset --hard {}" \;
```